# Jenkins: Force job to run on same node as required workspace

Tags: jenkins, label, nodes

so in my organisation we run unit test jobs on top of the workspace leftover from our build jobs. This works fine when the unit test job is run on a schedule at night, as a downstream project of the build job. The problem arises when someone tries to run the unit test jobs manually, as we have a number of nodes put under a label and the build jobs pick a node based on Jenkins algorithm, so there's no guarantee the unit test job will pick the correct slave.

Basically my question is, is there a way to force our unit test job to keep trying different slaves until it finds the required workspace, or some other way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of plugins that allow you to re-schedule failed builds ([here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Retry+Failed+Builds+Plugin), [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Naginator+Plugin) and [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Periodic+Reincarnation+Plugin)), but none of them supports assigning a rescheduled build to a different slave and iterate over the list of all slaves.

A better solution in your case may be to use the [Copy to slave plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin), which would allow you to copy the relevant files from the workspace of the slave back to the master on success and copy them to the slave before running the build. This way you could avoid failing builds altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and in-depth response! Unfortunately, I fear that using the Copy to Slave plugin's functionality to copy the workspace to master and back to slave before unit test job may take too much network resources, as our builds can get quite large.

Comment: Then I guess the solution would be to tie interdependent jobs to the same slave.